# SQL pivot with values calculated previously rather than using aggregate function

Tags: sql-server, dataset, pivot, iif

I am working with a **dataset** and I'm required to **calculate probabilities** for certain days of past years. Here is what the dataset looks like:

```
ID   STATION ID   DATE         ELEMENT ID   00     01     02     03......23
1    6106000      2009-05-11   110          2550   900    1050   1550    3000
2    6106000      2009-05-12   110          380    1400   1550   5090    200
3    6106000      2009-05-13   110          500    1250   800    3550    4020
```

I am not able to find a way to show the values I want in a **Pivot table**. Here is what I have in SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT 
Convert(char(15),[DATE],107) AS 'Date',
Format([DATE],'MMM dd') AS 'Day',
Probability = Cast(Round(((
IIf([00]>1410,1,IIf([00]=0,1,0)) + 
IIf([01]>1410,1,IIf([01]=0,1,0)) + 
IIf([02]>1410,1,IIf([02]=0,1,0)) + 
IIf([03]>1410,1,IIf([03]=0,1,0)) + 
IIf([04]>1410,1,IIf([04]=0,1,0)) + 
IIf([05]>1410,1,IIf([05]=0,1,0)) + 
IIf([06]>1410,1,IIf([06]=0,1,0)) + 
IIf([07]>1410,1,IIf([07]=0,1,0)) + 
IIf([08]>1410,1,IIf([08]=0,1,0)) + 
IIf([09]>1410,1,IIf([09]=0,1,0)) + 
IIf([10]>1410,1,IIf([10]=0,1,0)) + 
IIf([11]>1410,1,IIf([11]=0,1,0)) + 
IIf([12]>1410,1,IIf([12]=0,1,0)) + 
IIf([13]>1410,1,IIf([13]=0,1,0)) + 
IIf([14]>1410,1,IIf([14]=0,1,0)) + 
IIf([15]>1410,1,IIf([15]=0,1,0)) + 
IIf([16]>1410,1,IIf([16]=0,1,0)) + 
IIf([17]>1410,1,IIf([17]=0,1,0)) + 
IIf([18]>1410,1,IIf([18]=0,1,0)) + 
IIf([19]>1410,1,IIf([19]=0,1,0)) + 
IIf([20]>1410,1,IIf([20]=0,1,0)) + 
IIf([21]>1410,1,IIf([21]=0,1,0)) + 
IIf([22]>1410,1,IIf([22]=0,1,0)) + 
IIf([23]>1410,1,IIf([23]=0,1,0)))/24.0)*100.0,0) AS int)
FROM 
ON_2
WHERE 
((([ELEMENT ID])=110) AND 
(([STATION ID])='6106000') AND 
((Day([DATE])) BETWEEN 1 AND 15) AND 
((DatePart("m",[DATE]))=12))) AS BaseData
PIVOT 
(MAX([Probability]) 
FOR [DATE] 
IN ([2000],[2001],[2002],[2003],[2004],[2005],[2006],[2007],[2008],[2009],[2010],[2011])) AS PivotTable
```

As you can see, I am performing a **set of operations in the SELECT section** that includes `IIf statements` and some other math. After I got the values I wanted, I assigned the values to 'Probability', which is what I used in the **PIVOT section**, but my results are the following:

```
Day     2000  2001  2002  2003....2011
Dec 01  NULL  NULL  NULL  NULL....NULL
Dec 02  NULL  NULL  NULL  NULL....NULL
Dec 03  NULL  NULL  NULL  NULL....NULL
.
.
Dec 15  NULL  NULL  NULL  NULL....NULL
```

I have already tested the IIf calculations and all the math. I am able to obtain the numbers I want , but when I translate it into a Pivot table I cannot see the values, only NULL as you can see.

I would really appreciate your help, thanks for your time!

Comment: you need to use datepart(year, date) instead of Convert(char(15),[DATE],107) AS 'Date'

Comment: Thank you SOOO much. That totally made it!! :)

Comment: adding it as answer to close out the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use

```
  datepart(year, date)
```

instead of

```
  Convert(char(15),[DATE],107) AS 'Date'
```